# What can cause Chrome to give an net::ERR_FAILEDwhen dooing a request from a vue frontend to C# Api using axios?

Tags: c#, typescript, vue.js, http, axios

I have an C# Backend+API which I access from my Vue Application. To do the Requests I use axios. I have an Endpoint in C# with the following code

```
  // GET: api/Timezone
        public HttpResponseMessage GetTimezoneData()
        {
            var timezones = _service.GetSmcTimezones();
            var osTimezones = _service.GetOSTimezones();
            var resp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(osTimezones);
                
                //new JsonResult { Data = osTimezones, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent(resp, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            return response;
        }
```

I acces this request in the frontend with following code:

```
const config:AxiosRequestConfig = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://localhost:44333/api/Timezone/',
  headers: { }
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
  }
}
```

The weird thing is, that I can access the data when using Postman, but when sending the request from the frontend the requests fails. I recieve a **(failed)net::ERR_FAILED** code and I dont get any response data.
[image] Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: But you probably should get any info in devtools/Network. What error code do you have ? I mean - 404, 502, 503 etc...

Comment: Strange, because `status: 200`. What do you have in console?

Comment: Did you try to use only `/api/Timezone/` as a url parameter?
Try also to remove backslash from the end of url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225462/discussion-between-fbe106360-and-captain-yossarian).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify Content-Type header?

```
const config:AxiosRequestConfig = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://localhost:44333/api/Timezone/',
  headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
    }
};
```

Comment: I did, it doesnt make a difference